# Javascript or Jquery Filter out selected object for other selection with same data

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

i want create a form to select winner with rank 1, 2, 3.
i would like to ask how can i filter out the data is selected in other selection for the rest two select element?
if user select rank1: Name 2, then the Name 2 should not display in rank2, rank3.
if none of element is selected, will display all name for three selection.
eg.:

```
<select id="rank1">
<option value="0">Select One</option>
<option value="1">Name 1</option>
<option value="2" selected>Name 2</option>
<option value="3">Name 3</option>
<option value="4">Name 4</option>
</select>
<select id="rank2">
<option value="0">Select One</option>
<option value="1">Name 1</option>
<option value="3" selected>Name 3</option>
<option value="4">Name 4</option>
</select>
<select id="rank3">
<option value="0">Select One</option>
<option value="1">Name 1</option>
<option value="4">Name 4</option>
</select>
```

i try to find solution but can't get it. if could give some hint to help is appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

For two select boxes you could do something like this:

```
$('#rank1').change(function () {
     if ($('#rank2').val() == $(this).val()) $('#rank2').val('0');

     // Restore all hidden options for second select box
     $('#rank2 option').show(); 

     // Hide option selected in the first select box
     $('#rank2 option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').hide();
});
```

You should be able to easily adapt it for an additional one.

Answer (score 0):

All depends on the structure of your code.

But you can check [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) or [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Can you show us what structure are you using for?